# Django rest framework, serializer invalid when sent through Angular

Tags: python, django, angular, post

I'm having a problem where when I make a post request from my Angular application served through Django I get invalid serializers, even if the output is correct.

I console log the sent data:

```
{"email":"example@gmail.com","username":"example","password":"plaintextforthisexample","confirm_password":"plaintextforthisexample"}
```

Which gives me the response Bad Request (which I have set to happen when `serializer.is_valid()` is `false`).

However, if I copy and paste what's in the console log into the browsable API under raw data it accepts it and creates a user.

I can successfully send `get-requests` to the same API and get the data back, and the permissions for getting and posts are the same, although that would result in another type of error.
The content type is correct as well, when not I get a 415. If the URL is wrong I get a 500. And I can see on the Django server log that post requests are coming in.
Could it be because I'm running it from an angular template and not a Django one?

EDIT:

Picture of the console:[image]

Comment: @georgewg i think django wont process the request, if Access control header is not defined, correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @marcus can you check in your developer console that your request has been sent or not ( might be request parameters not sent properly from your angular app )

Comment: @AsifMohammed I believe it has, I edited my post with a link

Comment: @marcus can you share the code of model class, serializer class and your angular component

Comment: @AsifMohammed Sorry for the delay, I fixed a part of it, ran into another issue and it seems to be working. 
So First I had a syntax error causing me to post a non-JSON formatted dict, then it stopped working even on the api-side. My theory is that I used the same password to create too many accounts, but I'm unsure. Thank you for your help regardless

Answer (score 0):

Issue 1: The console logged output that worked in Django was not the one actually being sent, resulting in a JSONParse error.
It looked like something like this

```
function(formobject){
let payload = JSON.stringify(formobject)
console.log(payload)

return formobject
```

Issue 2: Now Django gives my my custom response on arrival:

`Status:'Bad Request' 
Message:'Data does not fullfill requirements for creating a user'`

And does not allow me to copy-paste the JSON-output from the console into the API raw data-form.

Solved by not using the same password I had been using for about 15 tries. Seems Django detects common passwords, has not been fully tested.